# PCRE: Different behaviour for \w on different servers

Tags: php, kohana, pcre

I'm using the routing system of Kohana for my own application, and when defining the pcre pattern for a tag of the url, my localhost behaves differently from the production server.

I have this route:

```
Route::set( 'list', 'list(/tagged/<tags>)',
            array('tags'=>'[\w\d\-\+]+') );
```

This used to work fine, until the day someone used a tag that contained not "standard" characters (ñ). In my localhost there is no problem, but In production server the system is not able to found the route.

In production code I need to modify the pattern and explicitly add the 'ñ' to the allowed characters!

```
'\pL[\w\d\-\+ñ]+'
```

The question is, why? Ok, it works now that I added the 'ñ', but it is going to fail again sooner or later!

Comment: Kohana uses the "u" modifier to the matching, so it probably means that PCRE was not compiled with Unicode support, or you are not using a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: I think unicode is supported on the system 'cause install.php tells me so. I bet is the locale settings @mario pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the different Unicode character classes you can use here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop With that said, you will be able to use something like this:

```
Route::set('list', 'list(/tagged/<tags>)', array('tags'=>'[\p{L}\p{N}\-\+]+'));
```

1. `\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language.
2. `\p{N}` any kind of numeric character in any script.

I've tested this out on ideone.com. [View example](http://www.ideone.com/Xs9TA).

Answer (score 3):

Since the meaning of `\w` is locale-dependent, your production server probably has a clean C locale, whereas your development system includes extended character codes.

IIRC using the `/u` unicode modifier allows `\w` to match all "letter" characters. If Kohana doesn't allow specifying modifiers, add it inline with `(?u)[...]`. Or maybe in your case you only need to repeat `\p{L}` within the square brackets:

```
'\pL[\w\d\-\+\p{L}]+'
```

Comment: the kohana system ends adding the /u to the final pattern, still not working, anyway I didn't know the locale behaviour.